# Construct a numpy array from a C structure using ctypes. ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

Consider the following code:

by_ref.h

```
typedef struct OutPutImage{
    double *** output_img;
    int nb_images;
    int nb_cols;
    int nb_rows;
}opi_;

void test_output_images(struct OutPutImage * out, int nb_images, int nb_cols, int nb_rows);
```

by_ref.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "by_ref.h"

void test_output_images(struct OutPutImage* out, int nb_images, int nb_cols, int nb_rows){
    out->nb_images = nb_images;
    out->nb_cols = nb_cols;
    out->nb_rows = nb_rows;

    out->output_img = (double***)malloc((nb_images) * sizeof(double**));
    for(int i = 0; i < nb_images; i++){
        out->output_img[i] = (double**)malloc((nb_cols) * sizeof(double*));
        for(int j = 0; j < nb_cols; j++){
            out->output_img[i][j] = (double*)malloc((nb_rows) * sizeof(double));
            for(int k = 0; k < nb_rows; k++){
                out->output_img[i][j][k] = 0;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

and

by_ref.py

```
import ctypes
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
import numpy as np

class OutPutImage(ctypes.Structure):

    _fields_ = [('output_img', npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.double, ndim=3)), 
                ('nb_images', ctypes.c_int), 
                ('nb_cols', ctypes.c_int),
                ('nb_rows', ctypes.c_int)]

    _libc = ctypes.CDLL("./by_ref.so")

    def __init__(self, nb_images=None, nb_cols=None, nb_rows=None):
        self.nb_images = nb_images
        self.nb_cols = nb_cols
        self.nb_rows = nb_rows

if __name__ == '__main__':
    libc_adm = ctypes.CDLL("./by_ref.so")
    libc_adm.test_output_images.restype = ctypes.c_int
    libc_adm.test_output_images.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(OutPutImage), ctypes.c_int,
                                            ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]

    output_image = OutPutImage(1, 2, 3)
    libc_adm.test_output_images(ctypes.byref(output_image), 4, 5, 6)  
    print(np.array(output_image.output_img, dtype=np.float))    # error ocures here
```

When I make and run this code using the following Makefile

```
by_ref: by_ref.so
    python by_ref.py

by_ref.so: by_ref.o
    gcc -shared -o by_ref.so by_ref.o

by_ref.o: by_ref.c
    gcc -c -Wall -fpic by_ref.c -o by_ref.o
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "by_ref.py", line 46, in <module>
    print(np.array(output_image.output_img, dtype=np.float))
ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string
make: *** [Makefile:2: by_ref] Error 1
```

I am sure `test_output_images` is doing what it is supposed to do. However I can't build the numpy array from the data in the structure. How do I accomplish this? Also, when do I free the memory?
Thanks.

**Edit:**

If I use `np.ctypeslib.as_array(output_image.output_img)` I get the same error:

```
ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string
```

**Update:**

If I use `x = np.ctypeslib.as_array(( ctypes.c_double*array_length ).from_address( ctypes.addressof(output_image.output_img) ))`, where `array_length=nb_images*nb_cols*nb_rows`, then I avoid the error described above, but the new array x contains garbage and it can't be reshaped.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in NumPy 1.15.x. Either downgrade to 1.14.6 or older, or upgrade to 1.16.0 or newer.

Comment: My numpy's version is 1.18.5, so it should be ok.

Comment: I get the same error with numpy version 1.16.0 too.